# How do I track internal search analytics in Google Analytics for a separate specific, non-site search

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, search, site-search

We're currently using Google Analytics to track internal site search.

Query parameter in View settings for this is set to 'q' as results are returned as '/search?q=publications'. This works well and provides us with data on search terms etc.

However, we have other content within the site that has its own seperate search, where users can search a repository for publications. When a user searches this repository using this search the results for this are returned as '/search?cr=AnyField!Contains!publication'

My question is, how do I set something up in Google Analytics so that I can also start getting search analytics for this second searchable repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enter up to 5 different query parameters for the site search:

> In the Query Parameter field, enter the word or words that designate an internal query parameter, such as "term,search,query". Sometimes the word is just a letter, such as "s" or "q". Enter up to five parameters, separated by commas.

Cf. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264?hl=en